# Uncaught ReferenceError: dicomParser is not defined

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, dicom, cornerstone

> Uncaught ReferenceError: dicomParser is not defined
>   hr.onreadystatechange   @   cornerstoneWADOImageLoader.js:4156

I'm doing my application with backbone, node.js and require.js.

`CornerstoneWADOImageLoader` fails because it doesn't find `dicomParser`, but I have defined it.

To use `cornerstoneWADOImageLoader` needs jQuery, cornerstone and dicomParser.

Is anything wrong?

Also `Uncaught cornerstone.enable(element);` returns this error

> TypeError: element.appendChild is not a function

Code:

```
//boot.js
require.config({
        paths: {
        jquery:                 '/js/lib/jquery',
        jqueryui:               '/js/lib/jquery-ui',
        'jquery.ui.widget' :    '/js/lib/jquery.ui.widget',
        underscore:             '/js/lib/underscore',
        backbone:               '/js/lib/backbone',
        text:                   '/js/lib/text',
        bootstrap:              '/js/lib/bootstrap.min',
        require:                '/js/lib/require',
        marionette:             '/js/lib/backbone.marionette.min',
        'cornerstone':            '/js/lib/cornerstone/dist/cornerstone',
        'dicomParser':            '/js/lib/dicomParser/dist/dicomParser',
        'jpx':                      '/js/lib/jpx.min',
        'cornerstoneWADOImageLoader':'/js/lib/cornerstoneWADOImageLoader/dist/cornerstoneWADOImageLoader'

},
shim: {
    'bootstrap': ['jquery'],
    'cornerstone':['jquery','dicomParser'],
    'cornerstoneWADOImageLoader':['jquery','cornerstone','dicomParser','jpx']
}
},

});
require(['jquery',
    'underscore',
    'app',
    'bootstrap'
], function ($, _, app) {
    app.start();
});


///dicomView

define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'text!templates/dicomViewTemplate.html',
    'cornerstone',
    'dicomParser',
    'jpx',
    'cornerstoneWADOImageLoader',

], function ($, _, Backbone, dicomViewTemplate) {

return Backbone.View.extend({

    render: function () {
        this.$el.append(dicomViewTemplate);


        var imageId = 'wadouri:dicom/55fc82d462eea6702a4c0a65'
        var element = $('#dicomImage');
        cornerstone.enable(element);
        cornerstone.loadImage(imageId).then(function(image) {
            cornerstone.displayImage(element, image);
        });

        return this;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue may be related to dicomParser supporting AMD but cornerstone does not (yet depends on it).  See if you can import dicomParser w/o using AMD modules (maybe via shim config)?  If that doesn't work, try removing the AMD bits from dicomParser.